# SharePoint's AJAXRefreshView not working correctly

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm working with lists in SharePoint2013. On button click a list items gets updated and an AJAX event is fired to refresh the list.
Found the event while searching the web: https://www.eliostruyf.com/ajax-refresh-item-rows-in-sharepoint-2013-view/
My code looks like this;

```
function onQuerySucceeded() {
// Set Ajax refresh context
    var evtAjax = {
        currentCtx: ctx,
        csrAjaxRefresh: true
    };
    // If set to false all list items will refresh
    ctx.skipNextAnimation = true;
    // Initiate Ajax Refresh on the list
    AJAXRefreshView(evtAjax, SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
}
```

And now to my problem. Half of the time the code works absolutely fine, but on the other half, somewhere inside this Ajax request, html is returned instead of json, which leads to an 'invalid char' exception.
I tried many variations, but never got it working. Does anyone have an idea how to handle this "challenge"?
Thanks for your time!
Cheers
Tobi

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.